# Retrieve custom object from JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I created a list and a model with custom objects. I want to retreive the objects that are in the list, however, I get an error message, that String can not be converted to Object.

```
String cannot be converted to ARMAJTermek
```

Swing automatically creates the JList, to which then I add a new model.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel<ARMAJTermek>();
TermekList.setModel(model);
```

I need this, because I'm using a custom object, that has properties and methods, which I need to invoke later. For this, I overrode the .toString method, like this:

```
@Override
    public String toString () {
        String toString = "";
        toString = this.nev+"\n"+this.cikkszam+"\n"+Integer.toString(this.bruttoKisker)+" Ft";
        return toString;
    }
```

This way, when I add an object to the JList, it appears as designed by the cell renderer (which is also unique, in a way that it displays JTextArea as a list element...).

```
for (int i... and lots of other code) {
    model.addElement(termek[i]);
}
TermekList.setModel(model);
TermekList.revalidate();
TermekList.repaint();
```

After adding objects to the list, it appears correctly, runs correctly, as when I select an object in the lists, it's methods run correctly. However, when I try to make a copy of the selected object for a different JList, I'm unable to retrieve them. I tried getting it from the list itself with

```
ARMAJTermek termek = (ARMAJTermek)TermekList.getSelectedValue();
ARMAJTermek termek = (ARMAJTermek)TermekList.getModel().getElementAt(TermekList.getSelectedIndex());
```

(Different functions, that's why some variables have the same name even being different types.)

But I get the message, that these Strings can not be converted to ARMAJTermek. But I don't need the String representation of the objects, I need the objects themselves. I mean, if it's methods can be run by clicking on their String representation in the list, I should be able to make a copy of them, right?

```
public class ARMAJTermek {
    String nev;
    String cikkszam;
    int bruttoKisker;

    public ARMAJTermek(String nev, String cikkszam, int bruttoKisker) {
        this.nev = nev;
        this.cikkszam = cikkszam;
        this.bruttoKisker = bruttoKisker;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        String toString = "";
        toString = this.nev+"\n"+this.cikkszam+"\n"+Integer.toString(this.bruttoKisker)+" Ft";
        return toString;
    }
}

public ui_main() throws  {
    initComponents();
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel<ARMAJTermek>();
    TermekList.setModel(model);

    ARMAJTermek termek[2];
    termek[0] = new ARMAJTermek("lorem", "ipsum", 1);
    termek[1] = new ARMAJTermek("lorem2", "ipsum2", 2);
}

public void addTermek(JList TermekList) {
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel<ARMAJTermek>();
    model.clear();
    if(TermekList.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
            TermekList.setSelectedIndex(1);
        }
    TermekList.removeAll();
    for ( int i = 0; i < termek.length; i++ ) {
        model.addElement(termek[i]);
    }
    TermekList.setModel(model);
        TermekList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        TermekList.revalidate();
        TermekList.repaint();
}

public void getTermek(JList TermekList) {
    ARMAJTermek termek = (ARMAJTermek)TermekList.getSelectedValue();
    ARMAJTermek termek = (ARMAJTermek)TermekList.getModel().getElementAt(TermekList.getSelectedIndex());
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also run and debug your code. The code snipplets, you've posted here give us no hint about the cause of your problem. Please don't post your complete code, but rather create a small runnable class that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy is it better?

Comment: this operations os TermekList is so confusing in code. They can't be static methods, and TermekList is just a class and not variable I assume. In public void addTermek(JList TermekList) { the Jlist that you are passing, does it has element of ARMAJTermek type or of String type. The stacktrace of exception can give you the line where exception is thrown. On that line, try to print the object type available in TermekList

Comment: TermekList is an object of the JList class (only it's CellRenderer is adjusted a bit). There TermekList adds the objects ARMAJTermek, which have the method .toString(), which makes them appear normally in the TermekList. the object type is String. (I need JTermek.)

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mre]._

Comment: *"is it better?"* It's not an MRE we can run, so no.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because already answered.

Answer (score 0):

I made it run by creating a new function inside the function, that can take and store the ARMAJTermek object:

```
ARMAJTermek termek = ARMAStaticFunctions.getTermek(TermekList);

public static ARMAJTermek getTermek(JList TermekList) {
        ARMAJTermek termek = (ARMAJTermek)TermekList.getSelectedValue();
        return termek;
}
```

And now it works as intended, not trying to convert objects to String.